# Can I call exportToExcel function on .cfc page?

Tags: javascript, excel, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

This project is supposed to be very simple. User should be able to click on the button that is placed on the top of my page. By clicking on the button, table records should be exported to an Excel spread sheet. I was thinking of creating  a simple function that will be triggered after the button is clicked. This will require sending parameters and calling the existing function on my .cfc page. I placed the `<cfif>` statement that will trigger the exportToExcel function on the cfc page. This did not work for me. I was wondering if export to spread sheet can be run on a .cfc page? If not, what is the other option to get this to work? I know that JavaScript has an option of converting .html page to an ms.excel but that doesn't look good and I can't use it in my project. Here is my code:

```
function exporToExcel(excelName){
    param = 'excelName=' + excelName;
    window.location.href = 'getExcel.cfc?method=getList' + param;
}


<cffunction name="getList" access="remote" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="excelName" type="string" required="no" default="">

    <cftry>
    <cfquery name="myList" datasource="test">
       //My query
    </cfquery>

    <cfif arguments.excelName NEQ ''>
        <cfset _createSpreadsheet(arguments.excelName, arguments.excelName, studentList, myList.getMeta().getColumnLabels())/>
    </cfif>
    <cfcatch>
        <cfoutput>#cfcatch#</cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Have your js function go to a .cfm page that calls the cfc function.

Comment: You're missing a `&` after `getExcel.cfc?method=getList`. The way its written now, param is added to the method name, and that will probably throw an error

Comment: @DanBracuk Can you please provide example? I haven't done anything similar to that before. Also I tried to search for that but no success. Thank you.

Comment: Your google search string is `coldfusion call cfc function`.

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm not sure if you read my question but I mentioned above that .cfc page did not work for me. Thank you.

Comment: You mean the question that included this:  `If not, what is the other option to get this to work? `?

Comment: Yes, I provided example of my current code above.

Comment: Have you tried fixing your javascript as per beloitdavisja?

Comment: @Leeish I tried that but no success. Also I have some include files that are required for my _createSpreadsheet function and I'm not sure if I can have include tags in .cfc page.

Comment: need to know what errors you are getting. In the browser debug tools what are the errors. Are you getting a 404 a 500? This is invalid `<cfoutput>#cfcatch#</cfoutput>` You need to do `<cfdump var="#cfcatch#">` as cfcatch is a struct. At the start of your function, just try doing `<cfdump var="test" />` and work until you can get it to output that. You aren't supplying a returnFormat in your function and I don't know what CF would try to default to.

Comment: You can have `cfinclude` tags in your cfc page but the fact that you are considering it might be a bad omen.

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks for your help. I was wondering if I can have cfinclude in my .cfc and if that will cause any other problems on my page.

Comment: (Edit) "Does not work" is a very ambiguous description  Without a complete repro case, or error messages, it is hard for anyone to do more than guess. Start smaller. Create a *really* basic - standalone - example. Nothing fancy, just a spreadsheet with a single value. If it still does not work, post the code along with an explanation of what it is actually doing and how it differs from what you expected.